# Json Format and Strings(Volley) android studio

Tags: android, json, android-studio, android-volley

I am sending a post request to an API, and to send the variables in json format I am creating a simple string like this:

```
String variables = "{\" name \ ": \" John \ ", \" age \ ": \" 24 \ "}";
```

And my question is if with special characters i can put the value of another string for example make it like this:

```
String variables = "{\" name \ ": \" textViewName \ ", \" age \ ": \" textViewAge \ "}";
```

So I make the strings with the editText inside

Can someone help me? I was thinking if isn't possible create a Json Obect or a Json Array? I don't know what is what I need here, and maybe later somehow make that the for example the value of the key "name" , is put it with the value of an editText.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your way it's not the proper way

1st You have to create a new class call it **User** for example

```
class User {

    String name;
    String age;

    User(String name, String age) {
       this.name = name;
       this.age = age;
    }
}
```

2nd step you can create a new object from that class and fill the data

```
//Here u can get the edit text value and pass it to the new object     
User user1 = new User("User Name","User Age");
```

The last thing u have to convert the **user1** object to Json using [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library from google

Gradle:

```
dependencies {
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.9'
}
```

and here's the magic

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();
 String json = gson.toJson(user1);
```